# QT Android App stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk

I am trying  to develop a Android App using QT/QML.

I am using QT 5.9.1, downloaded from https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.9/5.9.1/, while installing i checked Android option also.

Downloaded Android SDK - sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip and Android NDK - android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64.zip

Added both on QTCreator>Tools>Options>Devices

When compiling the program i am getting the following error.

```
../../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cstdlib:72:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:992: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
12:10:38: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project HellotestAndr (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.1 for Android armv7))
When executing step "Make"
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) recommends using Android NDK 10e, 
I have had the same problem with r16b, and as I see Qt does not support the updated version.

Comment: I am on Win7, Qt 5.10.0 MSVC2015 and using ndk-r16b version. Everything works fine. Maybe your problem is specific to Linux.